# Type safety: Unchecked cast from WebElement to List<WebElement>

Tags: java, selenium, runtime-error, typecasting-operator

My Code:-
File1.java

```
public int isListAvailable(String locator) throws Exception {
        WebElement ele = getObject(locator);
        List<WebElement> ls = **(List<WebElement>) ele;**
        //List<WebElement> ls1 = driver.findElements((By) ele);
        //List<WebElement> ls2 = driver.findElements(ele);
        int rowCount = ls.size();
        System.out.println("Last1 row=" + rowCount);        
        return rowCount;
    }

    public WebElement getObject(String locatorKey) throws Exception {
            WebElement ele = null;
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            try {
                if (locatorKey.endsWith("_xpath")) {
                    ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(locatorKey)));        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(locatorKey))));
    }

.....
...
....

    }catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
    }
            return ele;
    }
```

---

File2.java (catlisting_xpath is XPATH of the elements)

```
    public void search_List() throws Exception {
            
            if(con.isListAvailable("catlisting_xpath") >=1)
            {
                con.infoLog("Category List is available");
            }else {
                con.infoLog("Category List is not available");
            }
        }
```

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSKAO.png)

ERROR:-

java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to class java.util.List (org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tMnV.png)

the issue is, while I run or type this above the File1.java have got a warning at List ls = (List) ele;
Warning is
Type safety: Unchecked cast from WebElement to List

can anyone help out, how to solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebElement ele = getObject(locator);
List<WebElement> ls = (List<WebElement>) ele;
```

You are casting `List` to `WebElement` and that is not valid. I believe in your `getObject` method you are using `findElement` method to identify the locator. Instead of that use `findElements` method to get `List` of `WebElement`

Try like below,

```
List<WebElement> ls = driver.findElements(By.xpath(locator));
```

Comment: Thank you, totally agree with you....

Answer (score 0):

This is surprisingly complicated.

The cast operator (`(SomeType) someExpr)`) does 3 almost entirely unrelated things. You're confusing a few of them here, I think.

If the `SomeType` is a primitive numeric type (`int`, `char`, `double`, `float`, `long`, `byte`, or `short`), then **casts convert one thing to another**.

But that's where the conversion aspect of casts end. In all other cases you're merely telling the compiler: I *know* that the expression is of the type I am telling you it is. Sometimes, a runtime check is added (which will throw a `ClassCastException` if the expression turns out to not be of that type). Sometimes, the compiler just takes your word for it.

The generics part (`<WebElement>`) - that part is where the compiler will just take your word for it, and **that generates that warning**.

But that warning is completely irrelevant in this scenario: The problem isn't that part at all. The non-generics part (the `List`), that gets a runtime check. Because it gets a runtime check, the compiler won't warn: It's fine - if your type assertion turns out to be wrong, at runtime you'll get an exception that'll inform you about this.

So, the warning is about the `<WebElement>` part, but the error you get at runtime is about the `List` part.

Your WebElement **is not a list**. Perhaps you are attempting to create a list containing a single element. In that case, you'd want `List.of(ele);`. As I said, type-assertion mode casts do not convert anything, so you can't use it to convert an element to a list of just that element.